# Eshell and Dired are unable to extract port number from authinfo file

Tags: dired, tramp, eshell

My `default-directory` is:  `/ssh:lawlist@12.34.567.89#2222:/home3/lawlist`

My `.authinfo` file contains:  `machine 12.34.567.89 login lawlist password abcdefg`

The above-combination works just fine.  However, I would like to remove `#2222` from the `default-directory` and add `port 2222` to my `.authinfo` file.

If I remove `#2222` from the `default-directory` and add `port 2222` to my `.authinfo` file, neither Eshell nor Dired permit me to login to the remote server.

Eshell:

```
Waiting for prompts from remote shell ...
Timeout reached, see buffer `*tramp/ssh lawlist@12.34.567.89*` for details.
```

**Q**:  How can I remove `#2222` from my `default-directory` and force Eshell and/or Dired to extract `port 2222` from my `.authinfo` file?

---

**EDIT**:  The following is rough draft to add this new feature.  A maintainer of Tramp, @Michael Albinus, has suggested that this may break other aspects of Tramp and he has invited a discussion on tramp-devel@gnu.org regarding this issue.

1. Ensure you are using a version of Emacs containing the December 17, 2015 bug fix to `auth-source-ensure-strings` that was resolved by commit 9384953:  https://github.com/jwiegley/emacs/commit/938495317a02b06a6c512832d0c6d9530fcd7f2b
2. Define the following function:

```lisp
(defun get-auth-info (host user &optional port)
  (let ((info (nth 0 (auth-source-search
                      :host host
                      :user user
                      :port port
                      :require '(:user :secret)
                      :create t))))
    (if info
       (let* ((port (plist-get info :port))
              (secret-maybe (plist-get info :secret))
              (secret
                (if (functionp secret-maybe)
                  (funcall secret-maybe)
                  secret-maybe)))
           (list port secret))
       nil)))
```

3. Comment out `:port tramp-current-method` in `tramp-read-passwd`.  `tramp-current-method` is `"ssh"` and this prevents `auth-source-search` from returning a result if `.authinfo` contains a specified port other than `ssh`; e.g., `port 2222`.
4. Within `tramp-maybe-open-connection`, comment out and replace this section as follows:

```lisp
  ;; (when (string-match tramp-host-with-port-regexp l-host)
  ;;   (setq l-port (match-string 2 l-host)
  ;;         l-host (match-string 1 l-host)))

  (cond
    ((string-match tramp-host-with-port-regexp l-host)
      (setq l-port (match-string 2 l-host)
            l-host (match-string 1 l-host)))
    ((and l-host l-user)
      (let ((port (car (get-auth-info l-host l-user))))
        (when port
           (setq l-port port)))))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In auth-source.el, the port specification for Tramp is redefined. It must contain the Tramp method name, you cannot define the port number ssh is using.

Instead, I recommend to use a proper entry in `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host 12.34.567.89
    Port    2222
```

Of course, you could add other attributes like `HostName` and `User`.

Comment: Whenever you have some time, it would be wonderful if you could please take a look at my proposed solution (to add this new feature) in the edited question above and let me know what you think.

Comment: I see. However, it will break existing code, so I doubt it will go into the main branch of Emacs / Tramp.

If you want to discuss your solution in detail, we'll better move to the Tramp ML `tramp-devel@gnu.org`.

Comment: Thank you for taking a look at the proposed new feature -- I had a feeling it might break something that I was unaware of, which is why I did not want to post an alternative answer.  I would be happy to launch a feature request / discussion and will put this on my todo-list, but I have some work-related projects to attend to at the moment.  In the meantime, I will mark your answer as correct and put a notation in the edited question cautioning that this was a draft that the Tramp maintainer believes may break other aspects of of Tramp.

Answer (score 0):

TRAMP doesn't look for port numbers in the authinfo file; you can see the function `tramp-parse-netrc-group` for details. It looks like you could modify `tramp-host-regexp`, but I don't know off-hand if that would work out; later users of that information might fail if it's not just a hostname.